# Git Workflow Review

Tags: git

We have been looking at the git workflow on the Atlassian website

https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-gitflow

And based on that we have come up with our own spin on this workflow, which includes a UAT (user acceptance testing) layer

We also have a step where when we promote from develop-to-uat and from uat-to-master that creates a release.txt file, and commits it, which essentially becomes our version number on our website.

I am not overly happy with the release.txt process, I would prefer to use tagging, but the live site is on azure, so it is not uploaded from git, it is packaged up separately.

[image: Workflow Diagram]

In the diagram the comments relate to batch files we have created

- **git nf** = new feature
- **git mf** = merge feature (merge into develop)
- **git uat** = promote uat (merge develop into uat, generate release.txt, merge changes back into develop)
- **git nb** = new bugfix
- **git mb** = merge bugfix (merge into uat, generate release.txt, merge uat back into develop )
- **git live** = promote live (merge uat into master, generate release.txt, merge changed back into uat and develop)
- **git nh** = new hotfix
- **git mh** = merge hotfix (merge into master, generate release.txt, merge back into uat and develop)

I feel we are over enginering the solution, would appreciate any feedback on our worflow design. I can include the batch files too if that helps

Comment: i think this is a question not belonging to SO as there is no concrete problem in your question, maybe http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Where should it go then? I thought about code review, but there is no code